# adding and opening an .xls or excel file to solution results to cannot find file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I added a .xls file to my solution by using `Add>Existing Item` but when I used it in my code, it cannot find the file:

```
xlsWorkBook = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open("database.xls")
```

but if I use a local path such as `"C:\database.xls"` the code works.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify folder path it tries to get the file from the executable path. To use the file from your resources try this:

```
xlsWorkBook = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(My.Resources.MyFileName)
```

Or use the proper local path where your file is located:

```
IO.Path.GetFullPath(Application.StartupPath & "\..\..\Resources\") & "database.xls"
```

Comment: Application.startuppath is not working but i used System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), thanks for the idea! :)

Comment: when i try to pulbish and install the application, file not found exception occurs :( it only works in debug mode :(